# Java copy file to existing folder?

Tags: java, swing, path

I currently am trying to copy a file to a new location, but since the location already exists, I get an error.

Error:

```
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\Trevor\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
    at me.trevor1134.modinjector.ModInjector$3.actionPerformed(ModInjector.java:162)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

ModInjector.java:162:

```
                    Path modDir = Paths.get(fullPath);

Path newP = modDir;
                        Path oldP = mod.toPath();
                        try {
                            Files.copy(oldP, newP); //162
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

In the above, fullPath is determined by your OS, so it accesses the right directory.

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the old file?

Comment: @jbx Meaning? If the file is already in the new location then yes, but I don't want to delete the oldP file.

Comment: Note: you should `catch FileSystemException` before `IOException`; this way you'll know whether the error is due to a fs-level problem or I/O-level problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Files.copy (oldP, newP)`, do `Files.copy(oldP, newP, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)`

Comment: I tried that, copyoption only has the method this. I cannot use REPLACE_EXISTING

Comment: @Trevor your comment doesn't make much sense. `REPLACE_EXISTING` is a static member of `CopyOption`. No methods here...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ok, I still cannot use that. "REPLACE_EXISITNG cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: I did this, and now it is giving me a directory not empty exception.?

Comment: This means you are trying to overwrite a non empty directory; `newP` is probably a directory there. Do you want to copy a file or an entire directory tree?

Comment: @fge I want to copy a file (zip) to a directory.

Comment: OK, so `oldP` is a file but `newP` is a directory, right?